# Issue with Unzipping Multiple Files in Google Colab Notebooks

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I encountered an issue while trying to unzip four ZIP files from Google Drive using Google Colab notebooks. Despite not receiving any errors during the unzipping process, only one ZIP file was extracted successfully. I'm puzzled as to why the other three ZIP files weren't extracted, and I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if it's a loading-related problem.

Here's a brief overview of what I did:

Uploaded four ZIP files to Google Drive.
Used Google Colab notebooks to perform the unzipping process.
No error messages were shown during the execution.
However, only one folder was extracted, and the contents of the other three ZIP files remain inaccessible.
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue and ensure that all four ZIP files are correctly extracted. Thank you!

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this site about unzipping files with Google Colab Notebooks. How does your question relate to the others? Have you tried the answers to the other questions? How have they worked in your case? Providing this information will make it easier to get you an answer to your question. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+google+colab+unzip&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is a search query of questions related to yours.